# Googlesheet api php - filter query

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I would like to get filtered data from a google spreadsheet. For example if I have a column Name with values `John, David, John` => I would like to be able to get all the rows that have the `Name = John`.

```
$range = 'Sheet1!A2:A4';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
```

This gets me all the values within the range. I don't know how can I add a filter depending on the Name value.

Any help appreciated

Comment: AFAIK, this feature is not yet available in API, you can check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading) for more information about reading sheets. But you can set your own implementation to filter the data before showing it in the UI.